# JSON.NET Serialiser for Web API (mvc5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I've added a TypeFormatter so as to use JSON.NET as the principal serialiser/deserialiser for web api operations.

Given this simple action

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("api/myentity/")]
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateMyEntity(MyEntity entity)
 {
     // .. stuff to add
     // return 200, with some additional info
     return ResultOk(new {status = "Yay, added"});
 }
```

then the JSON.net type formatter (added to config also)

```
    public JsonSerializer Serializer { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify the media types that this MediaTypeFormatter handles
    /// </summary>
    public JsonNetMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json") { CharSet = "utf-8" });
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json") { CharSet = "utf-8" });

        Serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        return readStream.ReadAsJson(type, Serializer);
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        return writeStream.WriteAsJson(value, Serializer);
    }
```

When invoking the api operation with the following model:

```
application/json

{
    "Name":"ACME",
    "Phone":"0123456"
}
```

(Contents do not make a difference)

i get an `Unexpected token while deserializing object: EndObject. Path '', line 4, position 2.`

in other requests, the interesting thing is JSON.net is always reporting the row and character after the last char of the JSON (in this case line 4 == "}")

Anything i'm missing in serialiser config?

thanks

Comment: JSON.net is used by default. You don't need to define custom media type formatter for this. [source](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

Comment: do you know how to change the `NullValueHandling` of the underlying JSON.NEt serialiser?

Comment: yes, added a sample in answer below

Answer (score 2):

JSON.net is used by default in Web Api. `NullValueHandling` can be configured in `SerializerSettings`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not asking you why you want to implement your own media type formatter, you have your own reasons i presume. Could you please tell me where you get ReadAsJson extension method?

i found this implementation [StreamExtension](https://github.com/richardneililagan/JSON.net-Web-API-MediaTypeFormatter/blob/master/Extensions/StreamExtensions.cs), and i think there is small mistake at obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(instanceType). This expression will never be true, and second try of deserialization uses stream which would be consumed to the end...

i made small test with same exception as you are facing...

```
class Foo
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

public static Stream ToStream(string str)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(str);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stream = Program.ToStream(@"{ ""Test"" : ""TesT"" }");

    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };

        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        //  We want to try deserialization without specifying an explicit type first,
        //  then see if the resulting type is compatible with the type that is expected
        //  from the Web API stack stream.
        //  If not, then we try to read it again using an explicit type
        //  (although it probably won't work anyway still :p)

        var test = obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Foo)) ? obj : serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Foo));
    }
```

so solution is to implement your own deserialization method, you can use my example as start and simple add expected type to deserialization method, and remove finall test of course...

```
var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader, TYPE);
```